# Ubuntu won't boot after kernel upgrade

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, kernel, mount

I've followed the instructions given in [here](http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelBuild) so as to build the Ubuntu 4.4.22 kernel. The build was successful and I installed the new kernel as suggested there. But as soon as I reboot, i will face the below image on boot:

[image]

As it seems, it argues that the **UUID does not exists!** however, i made sure that this UUID is valid and belongs to ***/dev/sda1*** using ***sudo blkid*** command on the previous kernel.

I also tried adding ***GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true*** to ***/etc/default/grub*** but it did'nt worked! this time it argues that **/dev/sda1** does not exists!

Also, increasing the **bootdelay time** did'nt worked either.

Does anyone have any clue what's going wrong ?? any help on how to fix this is strongly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you building your own kernel, for starters?

Comment: just to add couple of printk() commands in some systemcalls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Finally after building the kernel for several times, I've found that this problem could sometimes happen if you use the below command for making the .config file:

```
make defconfig
```

Note that this oftentimes would happen if you are using a tool like VMWare Workstation. The reason for this relates to hardware enablement, as far as I'm concerned. I suggest using virtual box instead, as this just was another way i could solve this!

Anyway, the proper way to fix this is to make the .config file using the below command:

```
yes '' | make oldconfig
```

you can then use:

```
make menuconfig
```

using command above, you can customize .config file.

Hope this would help anyone who is building the kernel and facing the same problem in the future.